# Sending Array of characters as an parameter?

Tags: c

I'm trying to loop through an array, and send each data[i], to the add node function.I am not sure how I am supposed to pass the array when it is declared as :  char* data[400];

`addNode(data[i]) or addNode(&data) or addNode(&data[i])` ??

```
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
    addNode(&data[i]);
    }


NgramNodePtr addNode(const char *data)
{

   NgramNodePtr newNode = (NgramNodePtr) malloc(sizeof(data));

   //copy all of the node elements.
   strcpy(newNode->data, data);

   newNode->next = head.head;
   head.head = newNode;
   return newNode;
}
```

Comment: An array of characters (if terminated by a zero) is often called a *string*.

Comment: As for your problem, what is `addNode`? How is it declared? If you compile using different alternatives, what does the compiler tell you?

Comment: What's the prototype of `addNode` function ?

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: I added the add node

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: `data` is type of char**, and in while you use variable `i` as pointer, so use: `addNode(data[i])`

Comment: WTF is `NgramNodePtr`  ???

Answer (score 0):

`data` is type of char** and `addNode()` take char* as parameter. In loop you use variable `i` as pointer, so use: `addNode(data[i])` to dereference the char** as char*.

Comment: my add node is goes through until this line:   strcpy(newNode->data, data); is this the right way to copy data?

Comment: @Ahmed ::: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. That is 3 times, now. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) too.

Comment: If `newNode->data` is already allocated yeah, but `strcpy()` doesn't allocate any memory. `strdup()` is nearly the same as `strcpy()` but allocate the good memory space.

Comment: `data` is not `char** `.  `char* data[400];` is type [array 400 of pointer to char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char*+data%5B400%5D%3B).  Although similar in some ways,  an array is not a pointer.